# internet works but not in browser

Tags: windows-xp, networking

HI, I installed and uninstalled an external Wifi antenna on my XP laptop.  Now  I can not get the internet to work with any of my browsers, but th e internet does work  with my instant messenger.   please advise what I need to do. 
thank you very much

Comment: Reboot?  Check Proxy settings?

Comment: Hm. So now you're *not* using the WiFi anymore? Which "internet" are you using then?

Comment: What browser are you using?  I almost hate to ask, but could it be in "Offline Mode"?

Comment: When you try to browse, which error message do you receive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check your proxy settings in Internet Explorer. Go to Tools->Internet Options. Select the "Connections" tab and then click "LAN settings". The majority of the time "Automatically Detect Settings" should be the only box checked.

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering my question. I applied ur instructions, to no avail. please advise

Comment: Go back into the LAN settings and uncheck everything. (even the automatically detect settings).

Comment: Did you install a different external antenna or did you just reinstall an old one? It is possible the hardware is bad.